# Get string between first and third occurence of character

Tags: php, substring

I have many Strings looking like this: 
QR-DF-6549-1 and QR-DF-6549

I want to get these parts of the strings:
DF-6549

**Edit:**
So I also want to get rid of the "-1" at the end, in case it exists.

How can I do this with php? I know substr but I am a bit lost at this one.

Thank you very much!

Comment: for this *better use* **preg_match()** function instead of substr

Comment: Take a look at the [explode](http://php.net/explode) function..

Comment: Or `explode()` might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression is probably the best way given your sample data

```
//  ^    start matching at start of string
//  [A-Z]{2}-  must start with two capital letters and a dash
//  (    we want to capture everything that follows
//  [A-Z]{2}-  next part must start with two capital letters and a dash
//  \d+  a sequence of one or more digits
//  )    end the capture - this will be index 1 in the $match array allowed
if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]{2}-([A-Z]{2}-\d+)/', $str, $match)) {
    $data=$match[1];
}
```

Comment: Problem is, that QR and DF changes. It can also be other letters. Sorry that I didn't mention that in the question.

Comment: Then: `preg_match('/^[A-Z]+-([A-Z]+-\d+)/', $str, $match)`